# Does Exchange keep a record of the mail it's bounced?

Tags: exchange, email-bounces, microsoft-office-365

We've just migrated to Office 365 (from Google Apps, BTW) and due to some oversights (groups) have bounced an unknown amount of customer mail.

Does Exchange log bounced mail, and better yet, can I access those logs if I'm using Exchange via Office 365 (Medium Enterprise)?  I would guess if there's an answer it will invoke Powershell?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dan - yes, this should be available, if I'm understanding you right.  If you mean that groups didn't have SMTP addresses assigned properly and inbound email to them got bounced for "unknown recipient" then yes, it should show this in the Message Trace feature of the EAC.

Inside the EAC/admin portal, go to the Exchange admin area and then `Mail Flow` and then `Message Trace`.

From there, just do a basic trace.  If you want to specify the email addresses in question, click on the `Add Users` button in the appropriate section and then just type in the email address next to `Check` and don't hit anything but `OK`.

The search results should give you what you are looking for.  They aren't super detailed in the EAC though.

EDIT: if you want to export the results this is going to be done through the Powershell with Exchange Online.

Something like:

```
Get-MessageTrace -RecipientAddress bob@domain.com -StartDate 09/17/2013 -EndDate 09/19/2013 | fl
```

You could add a `where` statement at the end as well if you wanted just the failed ones as well as grabbing the trace details.

Something like:

```
Get-MessageTrace -RecipientAddress bob@domain.com -StartDate 09/29/2013 -EndDate 10/3/2013 | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq "Failed"} | Get-MessageTraceDetail | fl
```

To export either just add `> tracelog.csv` to the end.

Comment: That's awesome!  Any idea how I can export the results?

Comment: i added that to my answer.  If you like the additions feel free to upvote the answer. Thanks!